# Setup ceph for storage mailserver?

Tags: email-server, ceph

I have read some article but none of them tell how to use ceph for mail server will be like.

The most close to it: https://www.7layer.org/?p=313, but it was glusterFS

So is there any different when I'm using cephFS as a storage pool and make a soft-link from the storage pool to the actual path of mail storage?

Is it cephfs store email data as object-storage or file-storage

```
quanlm@ceph1:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            302M     0  302M   0% /dev
tmpfs            63M  7.9M   55M  13% /run
/dev/sda1        12G  2.1G  9.8G  18% /
tmpfs           311M     0  311M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           311M     0  311M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs            63M     0   63M   0% /run/user/1001
ceph-fuse       2.5G   48M  2.5G   2% /mnt/mycephfs
```

```
quanlm@ceph1:~$ cd /mnt/mycephfs/
quanlm@ceph1:/mnt/mycephfs$ ls
1111  123  ceph-deploy-ceph.log  mail  Maildir  test1.img
quanlm@ceph1:/mnt/mycephfs$ cd ~
quanlm@ceph1:~$ ll -h
total 100K
drwxr-xr-x  7 quanlm quanlm 4.0K Oct 31 07:16 ./
drwxr-xr-x  5 root   root   4.0K Oct 30 08:57 ../
-rw-------  1 quanlm quanlm  20K Oct 31 05:53 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--  1 quanlm quanlm  220 Oct 29 04:41 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r--  1 quanlm quanlm 3.8K Oct 29 05:08 .bashrc
drwxrwxr-x  3 quanlm quanlm 4.0K Oct 31 02:00 .byobu/
drwx------  3 quanlm quanlm 4.0K Oct 29 07:25 .cache/
-rw-rw-r--  1 quanlm quanlm  20K Oct 31 04:37 ceph-deploy-ceph.log
-rw-rw-r--  1 quanlm quanlm 1.1K Oct 29 05:49 .cephdeploy.conf
drwxrwxr-x  2 quanlm quanlm 4.0K Oct 31 04:45 cluster/
drwxrwxr-x 10 quanlm quanlm 4.0K Oct 31 07:25 dovecot-ceph-plugin/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 quanlm quanlm   19 Oct 30 08:42 mail -> /mnt/mycephfs/mail//
lrwxrwxrwx  1 quanlm quanlm   22 Oct 30 07:33 Maildir -> /mnt/mycephfs/Maildir//
-rw-r--r--  1 quanlm quanlm  655 Oct 29 04:41 .profile
-rw-------  1 root   root   1.0K Oct 30 07:57 .rnd
drwx------  2 quanlm quanlm 4.0K Oct 31 03:58 .ssh/
-rw-------  1 root   root   5.4K Oct 31 04:45 .viminfo
-rw-rw-r--  1 quanlm quanlm  174 Oct 31 03:59 .wget-hsts
```

P/s: Postfix, dovecot and squirrelmail installation from this guide: https://www.ionos.com/community/email-office/email/set-up-a-postfix-mail-server-with-dovecot-and-squirrelmail-on-ubuntu-1604/

P/SS: The system is work just fine but in this way, I only create a link for each user manually, like a user quan didn't on the soft-link so on the others server don't have it mail data storage

Answer (score 1):

CephFS for mail storage works.

You will have to do just some tunning. In our case, we decreased: bluestore_min_alloc_size_hdd and of course enabled compression. If you store your emails on SSDs, the option is bluestore_min_alloc_size_ssd and should be already low enough.

However, we still have a small setup with 240GB of emails and slowly grwoing.